# I am using Microsoft translator local sdk in my app for offline text to text translation, its not working in android kitkat

Tags: android, microsoft-translator

```
int result = Translator.start(mContext, new Translator.ServiceListener() {
.....
}
```

it return  `ERROR_APP_MISSING_SIGNATURE = 51`;
in kitkat, but its work fine in `marshmallow` and later android api versions

Comment: How to get this local SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like KitKat is returning multiple signatures, and the local sdk is only expecting one signature. you can fix by changing the check in `checkAppSignature()` method of `TranslatorImpl.java` to:

`if (packageInfo == null || packageInfo.signatures == null || packageInfo.signatures.length == 0) {`

I will look into updating GitHub with the fix.